# I am try retrieve data from my datatable which is located on index zero but I am unable to access it C#

Tags: c#, ado.net

```
byte[] file = (byte[]) dt1.Rows[0];
```

Comment: This wont work, as you ar etrying to typecast entire row into Byte[]. Use the row

byte[] file = (byte[]).dt.Rows[0]["ColumnNamw"]

Comment: What's the error message, if any, that you get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this way out:

byte[] file = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["ColumnName"];

OR

byte[] file = (byte[])dt.Rows[0][ColumnIndex];

Or

you can also grab your data using DataReader instead DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast a data table row to `byte[]`. You need to specify the cell too...

```
byte[] file = (byte[])dt1.Rows[0][0]
```

assuming you want the data from column 0 of row 0.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try something like this?

```
var file = dt1.Rows[0]["FieldName"]
```